# Use a python script on iOS app

Tags: python, xcode, swift

I have a simple python file that I want to run it within my Xcode project (Swift) and I want to run the file so It go along the swift file as if it was written in swift. I have seen this but with OS X I don't know if this is the same as in iOS but I am pretty new in Xcode. This is the video I saw on how to do this but it doesn't tell me how to use it with swift. [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d6VRvLjcPfU)

Comment: Does [this](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/swift-context-manager-implementing-python-context-manager-in-swift-f327b2b4a7d7) help?

Comment: Thanks! I will try this out!